# Core Data or .Plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsarray, plist

I would like to create an application that stores 3 informations:

1. the patient's name (string)
2. the test result (int) and
3. the date of testing.

In the first `UIView`, a `TableView` will show up with a list of patients. By clicking on any cell in the `UIView`, the list of tests with dates that the patient performed is shown. I'm just starting on Objective-C and have not found the best way to do this. Using Core Data and SQLite? Using a .Plist file? And for arrays? I will create 3 arrays?

My first idea was to create an `NSMutableArray` of patients and each associate a test, but in this case for a patient to carry out various tests, his name will shown repeated in the list of patients. I could`t find thought how could filter the`NSMutableArray` (with predicate?) To display the test data for a single patient in the next screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit too generic to answer it properly.

But if you save patient information you should definitely consider encrypting the data.
CoreData sounds a bit overkill if you save a very limited amount of data and you don't want to worry about data management, schemas and migrations.

A PLIST storage sounds like a perfectly reasonable solution.
Regarding your data structure.

You have an array of patients in your first view. When you select a cell to get to the next view, you'll pass the selected patient to the next view.